# Can a jsondatasource for datapages in xamarin can be loaded from file

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-datapages

I want to load a json file as a datasource for datapages in xamarin.forms

i tried a lot but not happening

can anyone help me with it

Comment: "I tried a lot" - show us what you tried.  Post the applicable portions of your code.

Comment: i tried to parse the json and load it to a var